# Anylogic - How to use a relative path to excel file

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to use a realtive path to the excel file I have connected to my AnyLogic simulation model. The excel file is in the same folder as the model. Can someone give me a clue please? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

When browsing for the Excel file, you can choose what path should be used (relative or absolute) by clicking the icon next to the Browse... button:

[image]

[image]

When finished, the path to the file will be shown in the File field. By default, it uses relative path like input.xlsx